# Best way to store uploded documents on web application

Tags: file-upload, architecture

I have one web application where user can upload multiple files( one file size up to 20MB) for one record.

Currently, storing files on file system. But still wanted to know which is the best way.

**Architecture **

Auth , business logic and user interface are on different computers. A request travel through all these  servers. user interface does have file system access .

When the user download a file, UI request auth , auth ask BL and BL will give db path only, and then auth will encode this file and give it to UI.

Is it a correct way? What are the other options?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the best solution would be to separate the logic for working with files and develop a separate microservice that would save files, for example to distributed file storage, through an [s3 api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Welcome.html) and also give them back to the client.

There are various distributed file storages, I would not want to advertise one of them, but you can get to know them separately by [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_distributed_file_systems).

Such an architecture scales better and is more secure because you hide direct access to the database or file system and you can control access and have logic in this storage microservice. You also have the opportunity to have the benefits of s3 api replacing distributed storage as you  like, for example, when developing, use a lighter solution, and in production more complex (most distributed systems support s3 api).

With this scheme, you can separately scale the storage microservice itself.

Regarding your scheme, depending on which authorization and authentication scheme you use, the best solution would be for the initial request to come immediately to the business logic (if you are not using the api gateway), and the business logic itself would decode the authorization token or ask authorization service (it depends on your authorization and authentication scheme). Thus, the authorization microservice would not have to deal with work related to files and he would not know anything about this.

I recommend to get acquainted with various architectural schemes of authorization and authentication in microservice architecture, it is very interesting, even if you do not plan to use a microservice architecture. There is a good description of the various basic authentication and authorization patterns in this [book](https://livebook.manning.com/book/microservices-patterns/chapter-11/44).